# Google Wallet Postback Blank

Tags: android-pay

**Solution**

The server logs are telling me that I was getting a 301 redirect. This is an .htaccess issue, not GWallet. The redirect was stripping my POST data, leading to a blank request. Thanks everybody for your help.

---

I'm trying to process the postback from Google Wallet, but I'm not getting the proper data from Google Wallet to start.

Apache's error_log doesn't have any entry for my postback. The access_log shows the following for every attempt at a postback request:

```
[source-ip-1] - - [16/Sep/2013:15:18:05 +0000] "POST /google-postback.php HTTP/1.1" 301 293 "-" "Google-In-App-Payments; (+http://www.google.com/payments)"
[source-ip-2] - - [16/Sep/2013:15:18:06 +0000] "GET /google-postback.php HTTP/1.1" 200 20 "-" "Google-In-App-Payments; (+http://www.google.com/payments)"
[source-ip-1] - - [16/Sep/2013:15:18:36 +0000] "POST /google-postback.php HTTP/1.1" 301 293 "-" "Google-In-App-Payments; (+http://www.google.com/payments)"
[source-ip-2] - - [16/Sep/2013:15:18:36 +0000] "GET /google-postback.php HTTP/1.1" 200 20 "-" "Google-In-App-Payments; (+http://www.google.com/payments)"
```

A reverse-DNS shows both IPs are google proxies.

The JavaScript performing the request is as follows:

```
<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Success handler
    var successHandler = function(purchaseAction){
      if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.log("Purchase completed successfully.");
      }
    }

    //Failure handler
    var failureHandler = function(purchaseActionError){
      if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.log("Purchase did not complete.");
      }
    }

    function purchase()
    {
        console.log("Attempting to buy stuff");
        google.payments.inapp.buy({
            'jwt' : '<?=$jwt?>',
            'success' : successHandler,
            'failure' : failureHandler
        });
    }
</script>
```

I POSTed to my postback page myself with the JWT string I giving to Google Wallet's buy() function, and it decodes to what I expected:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [iss] => [my seller id]
    [aud] => Google
    [typ] => google/payments/inapp/item/v1
    [exp] => 1379106326
    [iat] => 1379102726
    [request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Piece of Cake
            [decription] => Virtual whazzit
            [price] => 10.50
            [currencyCode] => USD
            [sellerData] => id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j
        )

)
```

Originally, my postback looked like this:

```
<?php
require_once "google/googlefunctions.php";

$encoded_jwt = $_POST["jwt"];
$decodedJWT = JWT::decode($encoded_jwt, [seller_secret]);

$orderId = $decodedJWT->response->orderId;

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
echo $orderId;
?>
```

But Google's popup kept returning an error about not being able to verify the purchase (I forget the exact message). After trouble-shooting, I've decided to email myself to verify that I'm actually hitting the postback, and not being blocked by a seller id/secret credentials problem:

```
// google-postback.php
<?php
mail("my@email.com", "Purchase post", print_r($_POST, true));
?>
```

My response email is as follows:

```
Array
(
)
```

As far as I know, Google Wallet should be sending me a POST with a 'jwt' variable to decode that's identical to what I sent, but with a response, but I'm getting nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is your actual code? Showing just a mail command with a dump of an unset `$_POST` variable isn't helping much.

Comment: Sure! Changes posted. I was being terse for the sake of keeping it simple, but I went overboard. I hope this is enough information. Let me know if more is required.

Comment: First, you shouldn't debug this way. Use logs on your server and `tail -f <your log file>` command. Typically `access.log` and `error.log` for the virtualhost you're running this on. `access.log` will show you if the postback is even called. Use `error_log` PHP function to log to `error.log`. Ideally you should set a breakpoint via `xdebug` PHP extension and break when Google is reaching out to your service. Did you correctly setup the postback URL in Google Wallet Sandbox settings?

Comment: Granted, ideally I'd be using PHP logs, but I don't direct access to the file system, so I'm making as much as I can. The postback is set correctly, as evidenced by the fact that the postback script ends up emailing me whenever I attempt to complete a sandbox purchase.

Comment: The error message somewhat matters: it could simply be that Google isn't sending you an HTTP POST because "you are buying from yourself" - re: you can't use the same account for buyer and merchant. Or, perhaps overly simplistic, but check on the postback url you provided to Google and make sure they can get to it.

Comment: I've typically been warned by Google's in-app interface about buying from myself with a message describing that specific problem. My current issue ends up giving me a generic problem message.

Comment: I'll be more specific about that message: "Unfortunately, we could not confirm your purchase with the merchant's server. Your order has been canceled. Please contact the merchant if this problem continues."

Comment: So your postback is hit but the post body is empty?  If you curl data to your postback from an external network, is that content emailed?